# Winston doesn't pretty-print to console

Tags: node.js, winston

I'm trying to get Winston to pretty print to the console, so I stuck this in a file and ran it with node:

```
var winston = require('winston');
winston.cli();
winston.data({
  a: "test",
  of: "many",
  properties: {
    like: "this"
  }
});
winston.data('data', {
  a: "test",
  of: "many",
  properties: {
    like: "this"
  }
});
```

The terminal spit back the following (not exactly pretty) messages:

```
data:     a=test, of=many, like=this
data:    data a=test, of=many, like=this
```

I'm following the instructions on the [Winston Readme](https://github.com/flatiron/winston) ("Using winston in a CLI tool"). Am I misreading something? Missing a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I figured out the answer (the documentation is incorrect). If you use the constructor, and manually add transports, you can set options, both for winston, and for individual transports. Certain options need to be added to winston directly, while others need to be added to the transport.

E.g.:

```
var winston = require('winston');
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  levels: {
    trace: 0,
    input: 1,
    verbose: 2,
    prompt: 3,
    debug: 4,
    info: 5,
    data: 6,
    help: 7,
    warn: 8,
    error: 9
  },
  colors: {
    trace: 'magenta',
    input: 'grey',
    verbose: 'cyan',
    prompt: 'grey',
    debug: 'blue',
    info: 'green',
    data: 'grey',
    help: 'cyan',
    warn: 'yellow',
    error: 'red'
  }
});

logger.add(winston.transports.Console, {
  level: 'trace',
  prettyPrint: true,
  colorize: true,
  silent: false,
  timestamp: false
});

logger.add(winston.transports.File, {
  prettyPrint: false,
  level: 'info',
  silent: false,
  colorize: true,
  timestamp: true,
  filename: './nKindler.log',
  maxsize: 40000,
  maxFiles: 10,
  json: false
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't the numbers on the levels be in reverse order? E.g. error = 0 and trace = 9 https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#logging-levels

Comment: This is suitable for older versions of winston

Answer (score 34):

If you're using winston@3.0.0-rc0 then the accepted answer won't work. Try the following:

```
const winston = require("winston");
let date = new Date().toISOString();
const logFormat = winston.format.printf(function(info) {
  return `${date}-${info.level}: ${JSON.stringify(info.message, null, 4)}\n`;
});
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console({
      level: level,
      format: winston.format.combine(winston.format.colorize(), logFormat)
    })
  ]
});
```

The logs will have the following format:

It's colored BTW

```
2018-03-01T19:49:54.042Z-info: "----- Customer Details ------"

2018-03-01T19:49:54.042Z-info: [
    {
        "A": 1,
        "B": 2
    }
]
```

Comment: This should become the accepted answer @JoBu1324

Comment: This hardcodes the date to one value, and won't log the correct date in the log messages - they will all be the same (as shown in the example).

Answer (score 13):

Here's a solution for Winston v3+

```
  let winstonFormat = winston.format.json();
  if (NODE_ENV == "development") {
    winstonFormat = winston.format.combine(winston.format.json(), winston.format.prettyPrint());
  }

  const log = winston.createLogger({
    level: "info",
    format: winstonFormat,
    defaultMeta: {app: "myapp"},
    transports: [
      new winston.transports.File({filename: "/dev/stderr", level: "warn"}),
      new winston.transports.File({filename: "/dev/stdout"}),
    ],
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

I took @partycoder's answer and trimmed it down to use only the default logging levels that come with winston. It also doesn't reverse the order of the errors. 0 = highest priority.

```
winston.addColors({
  silly: 'magenta',
  debug: 'blue',
  verbose: 'cyan',
  info: 'green',
  warn: 'yellow',
  error: 'red'
});

winston.remove(winston.transports.Console);
winston.add(winston.transports.Console, {
  level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL,
  prettyPrint: true,
  colorize: true,
  silent: false,
  timestamp: false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a slightly better solution than Sam Gh's one:

```js
const winston = require("winston");

const logFormat = winston.format.printf(function(info) {
  return `${info.timestamp}-${info.level}: ${JSON.stringify(info.message, null, 4)}\n`;
});

const logger = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console({
      level: level,
      format: winston.format.combine(winston.format.timestamp()
                                     winston.format.colorize(), 
                                     logFormat)
    })
  ]
});
```

In this way, the log entry's timestamp is correct and not the hardcoded one.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue too but I came to meet it on git, and found some interesting trick that might be helpful about it.
[issue #1217](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1217)

First of all, the trick is in using

```
JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, 4) // This helps indent lines and make them readable
```

You can see it in this visual studio code screenshoot below for clear documentation
[how to use JSON.stringify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTEwr.png)

For example if you were using a console transporter you would create it like this

```
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console({
            format: printf((info) => {
                return `${info.timestamp} [${info.label}] [${info.level}] : ${info.message}\n 
            ${JSON.stringify(info.meta, null, 4)}`; // Meta as additional data you provide while logging
                ;
            })
        })
    ]
```

And use it like

```
Logger.info("Message text", { meta: metaDataHere } )
```

Comment: Where is printf from ?

Answer (score 0):

For the ones using NestJS

```
const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule, {
logger: WinstonModule.createLogger({
  exitOnError: false,
  transports: [
    new transports.Console({
      format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.errors({ stack: true }),
        utilities.format.nestLike('App name', {
          colors: true,
          prettyPrint: true,
        }),
      ),
    }),
    new LogtailTransport(new Logtail(process.env.logTail)),
  ],
}),
});
```

Basically

```
utilities.format.nestLike('App Name', {
      colors: true,
      prettyPrint: true,
    }),
```

does the trick